# Can I use the phrase "down the road" when the place I am referring to is actually higher than my position on the same road?

Tags: phrases

For example, let's say there is a library that is located on the same road as my house. However, altitude wise, the library is higher than my house. Is the sentence "The library is down the road from my house." still correct?

Comment: Generally yes, in my opinion, though if the altitude difference is obvious I might find myself saying "up the road" instead. I don't think this is the sort of thing that admits a strict rule.

Comment: @cruthers - and depending on the altitude involved, I might even say "up the hill".

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "down the road" is an *idiom.*

> Idiom: a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words. [Google]

The phrase does not refer to the literal idea of traveling downhill. In the example you've used, it has the meaning of "away from." Though not always true, it usually indicates "further along in the direction you were traveling."

It is common to use the phrase, even when referring to a location that is uphill from where you are.

Similar idioms include:

- Uptown: the residential area of a city or anywhere that isn't considered "downtown." Has no relationship to the direction "up."
- Downtown: the business or commercial district of a city. Has no relationship to the direction "down."
- Raining cats and dogs: a heavy rain that has nothing to do with cats or dogs.